# how to add an X=msgbox command using sendkeys vbs

Tags: vbscript, virtual, sendkeys, basic

when I try adding the `"` quotes in

```
X=msgbox"Writing",48,"Title"
```

but the quotes wont recognise.

I've tried using {} but that doesn't help either?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52765029/edit) and explain more your request, because it is unclear ?

Comment: What does this have to do with SendKeys?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to capture the result of the MsgBox in variable X, you need to put brackets around the parameters like so:

```
X = Msgbox("Writing",48,"Title")
```

Comment: no I mean it wont recognise the "" in send keys. I know for the brackets i know how too add them

Comment: @Zatando  Then redo your question and example code, because the mistake you put in there took me away from the problem you **do** seem to have. Put in the code you actually use for SendKeys.

Answer (score -1):

you have to put in chr(34) thats quotes so you should be using the code vvv

```
thewshkey.sendkeys "x=msgbox" & Chr(34) & "writing" & Chr(34) & ",48," & Chr(34) & "Title" & Chr(34)
```